# Opencv java IP camera mjpg stream

Tags: java, opencv, video-capture, ip-camera

I am trying to grab images from a IP cam for image processing using opencv java. The stream is in mjpg format and I am using opencv's VideoCapture to try to retrieve a image. I can grab a image from my webcam using videocapture but when I try to open a IP cam it will never open. I can also view test stream [here](http://construction.sfhs.com). I tried searching around for an answer but none pf them seem to work. I am on windows 7 with opencv 2.4.9. This is the code I am trying to get to work.

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
VideoCapture vc = new VideoCapture();
vc.open("http://construction.sfhs.com/mjpg/video.mjpg");
Thread.sleep(100);
while(true) {
    System.out.println(vc.isOpened());
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

It just outputs false

Comment: suggestion: check if your opencv is built with ffmpeg support.

Comment: @Kiran Hmm I think I just fixed it by changing my path variable to C:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x86\vc11\bin

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Try adding "opencv_ffmpeg249.dll" to the folder of your program.